# Create a sheet that isn't a warning message

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have [an app](https://github.com/Fedict/eid-mw/tree/master/plugins_tools/eid-viewer) that reads data from a smartcard. Since doing so can take a while, I'm using a modal sheet to prevent interaction with the app while data is being read:

```
[_spinner startAnimation:self];
[NSApp beginSheet:_CardReadSheet modalForWindow:_window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(endSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

Where `_CardReadSheet` shows `_spinner` and a localized text to the effect of "Reading data, please wait", `_window` is my main window, and `endSheet:returnCode:contextInfo` just tells the sheet to close.

The problem is that using a modal sheet is apparently meant only as an error or warning message, so showing it to the user in this way results in the default warning sound being produced. This is not the intent.

How can I make it not produce a sound? If I'm using the wrong way to show the sheet, or if using a sheet is not the right thing to do, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning sound is because you're asking NSApp to provide the sheet: it does so as an alert. I can't find an official source explaining why but this is what is happening.

To get a similar sheet but without any alert sound, call `beginSheet` on NSWindow instead of NSApp.

Quick example in Swift:

```
myExistingWindow.beginSheet(myNewSheet, completionHandler: nil)
```

And to close it:

```
myExistingWindow.endSheet(myNewSheet)
```